# Collection view interaction is not working on iPhone12 pro max

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

in one of my application i have implemented dashboard screen with collection view and  when user clicks on collection view cell's it is not interacting this is happening to only iPhone12 pro max users

currently i don't have that real time device to test but i have tested in iPhone12 pro max simulator and its working fine

can you please suggest what was the cause or any suggestions?
thanks in advance

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        customClassCollectionViewCellOne *cell = [[customClassCollectionViewCellOne alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        cell = (customClassCollectionViewCellOne *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"accountBalance_main_collectionview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.balanceArray = newbalanceArray;
        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];

        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        
        customClassCollectionViewCellTwo *cell = [[customClassCollectionViewCellTwo alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        cell = (customClassCollectionViewCellTwo *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QuickActions_main_collectionview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.quickActionList = viewModel.quickActionsList;
        cell.delegate = self;
        
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];


        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        customClassCollectionViewCellThree *cell = [[customClassCollectionViewCellThree alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        cell = (customClassCollectionViewCellThree *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GetInTouch_main_collectionview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.getinTouchList = viewModel.touchList;
        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

just informing
custom collectionview cell class contains sub collection view again

Comment: Can you show more code when tapped on that cell?

Comment: Hi son i have updated the code in cell for row can you please check

Comment: @mahe is it swift?

Comment: In did select just setting the values and calling the respective protocol listeners

Comment: @mahan it is in combination of both objective c and swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your view components to the cell's content view and not directly as a subview.

Comment: thanks @ronokim  i just tried and its working fine